# how to redirect to different page through ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

> this is my ajax code ,I can easily submit my form to php page in
>   backend

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$("#contact-form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'customerdata.php',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
    type:'post',
      success: function(response) {

        document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";

        if( response.hasOwnProperty('id') ) {
            window.location.href = 'index.php?booking=success&booking_id=' + response.id + '&user=' + response.email;
        }




       }
});
});




</script>
```

> Now here is my php code ,

```
    <?php
    $name=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['name'])));
$mail=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['email'])));
$phone=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['important_number'])));
$booking="ZOHO".crypto_rand_secure(10000,100000);
$typeofcab=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['the_cab'])));
$alt=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['alternate_number'])));
$drop=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['drop_address'])));
$pickup=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['pickup_address'])));
$source=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_SESSION["source"])));
$destination= trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_SESSION["destination"])));
$type=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_SESSION['type']))) ;
$date=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['journey_date'])));
$gotime= trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_SESSION["time"])));
$price= trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_SESSION["price"])));
$status="Pending";
$takenby="Pending";
$avail="Pending";
$driver="Pending";
$carnumber="Pending";
$password=$phone=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['important_number'])));
$need=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['need'])));
$vendorprice = price($price);

if(!isset($_POST['return_date'])){
    $return='NOT APPLICABLE';
    $returntime='NOT APPLICABLE';


}
else {
  $return=$_POST['return_date'];
    $returntime=$_SESSION["timeo"];
}



$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT  `email` FROM `users` WHERE email=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$mail);
$rock=$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($email);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
}



if($email !=$mail)
{

$query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO  `customerdata`( `vendorprice`,`price`,`name`, `email`, `phone`, `bookingid`, `source`, `destination`, `sourceaddress`, `destinationaddress`, `alternate`, `typeofjourney`, `journeydate`, `returndate`, `journeytime`, `returntime`, `status`, `availability`, `takenby`, `cabtype`, `drivername`, `carnumber`, `customerneed`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");


$query->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssssss",$vendorprice,$price,$name,$mail,$phone,$booking,$source,$destination,$pickup,$drop,$alt,$type,$date,$return,$gotime,$returntime,$status,$avail,$takenby,$typeofcab,$driver,$carnumber,$need);
$run=$query->execute();


$query_user=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`password`,`email`, `phone`, `bookings`,`name`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$query_user->bind_param("sssss",$password,$mail,$phone,$booking,$name);
$run_query=$query_user->execute();
$mailsent=sendmail($name,$mail,$booking,$type,$date,$gotime,$source,$destination,$price,$password,$typeofcab);





if ($run && $run_query ) {
  echo json_encode(array("id" => $booking, "email" => $email));

  // session_destroy();
  //header('Location: index.php?booking=success&booking_id='.$booking."&user=".$email."price=".$price."phone=".$phone);
//exit;
}
else {
  echo json_encode(array("error" => mysqli_error($db)));
//  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($db));
  // header('Location:index.php?failed');
  // exit;


}

}


else {

//  $yourURL="bookingconfirmation.php?route=oneway";

//echo ("<script>alert('This email already exists with us,please try different email'); location.href='$yourURL'</script>"); // redirect with javascript, after page loads
echo json_encode(array("failed" => $email));
//echo "this email already exists";


}




    ?>
```

> What I want is ,when the query is sucessfull ,i want to redirect my
>   user to different page with ajax ,like I was doing with php before
>   using headers ,by giving all the neccessary  url parameters ,any help
>   will be really appreciated t

Comment: You need to do it the same way as you already have in your code, using `window.location.href = ...`. You can not use a server-side redirect here - because you are making a _background_ request here, and everything you do on the HTTP level stays “in the background” here. So if your PHP script determines the destination URL dynamically, you have to pass that value back to your AJAX script, and then assign it as the new location there.

Comment: You can try 
`window.location.replace('index.php?booking=success&booking_id=' +id+'&user='+email);`

But I'm not 100% sure what do you expect to see. Do you want to add headers from ajax response to redirect request?

Comment: Same question as asked before, where do you think that `id` and `email` are coming from? ;) @inser

Answer (score 0):

you can write only window.location='You URL'; instead of  "window.location.href"

Answer (score 0):

Where do you think that `id` and `email` are coming from on client side? You need to return them correctly on php side, like in a `json`. Than you can handle the variables as properties of `response` in the `ajax` success callback.

```
<?php
if( $run && $run_query ) {
    echo json_encode(array("id" => $booking, "email" => $email));
}
else {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => mysqli_error($db)));
}
```

On client side use the `response` object, there are no variables passed as parameters, only as properties:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'customerdata.php',
    cache: false,
    data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response) {
        document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";

        if( response.hasOwnProperty('id') ) {                
            window.location.href = 'index.php?booking=success&booking_id=' + response.id + '&user=' + response.email;
        }
        else {
            alert(response.error);
        }
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but its returning empty parameters email and id

Comment: What do you get, when you call `customerdata.php` manually or what do you see in your browsers network console? Sounds like you have something else not working too ... @loGAN

Comment: Ihave edited the code please check ,actually there is an option of checking if email exists or not !! and what I am getting is alert stating undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in PHP, but try:
in php code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('id' => 'your_id', "email" => 'test@email.com'));
```

in js:

```
success: function(data) { var email = data.email; var id = data.id }
```

Answer (score -1):

if you need to redirect to another page via ajax then you have to do it with javascript or jquery ,, you can't do it with php. you can listen and capture response `echo 1;` or any other response from php and then in your `success` callback redirect to another page with `window.location.href="X"` or similar..

hope that helps you

Answer (score -1):

if you want to pass dynamic url to html then you can do this by passing dynamic url from php to ajax like

```
<?php
if ($run && $run_query ) {
  echo $booking;
  echo $email;
    $return['url'] = "index.php?booking=success&booking_id=".$booking."&user=".$email."price=".$price."phone=".$phone;
   $return['err_msg']  = '';
}
else {
    $return['url'] = '';
    $return['err_msg']  = "Error description: " . mysqli_error($db));
}
 echo json_encode($return);/* encode json data to get in html file*/
?>
```

and javascript code could be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#contact-form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'customerdata.php',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
    type:'post',
      success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); /*see server msg */
           var pd = JSON.parse(data); /*decode json data*/

           location_url = pd.url; 
        if (pd.url !='') {
             document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
             window.location.href = location_url;
        }
        else {
           var err_msg = pd.err_msg;
           if(err_msg != ''){
              $('#error').html(err_msg);
           }
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
        }
         },

     error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownerror) { }

       }
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Oh my god. Worst messy code an unecessarry double parses. Don't do that.